# PDO query to remove text from 3 MySQL tables at once?

Tags: pdo

As an absolute beginner in these things, I am stuck: I need to build a query to remove all occurrences of a string from 3 tables, something like

```
$sql = "UPDATE table_1, table_2, table_3 SET column=REPLACE(column, '$string', '')";
```

How can I build a prepared statement to do this? Something like

```
$sql = "UPDATE table_1, table_2, table_3 SET column=:column";
$q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':column'=>"REPLACE(column, '$string', '')"));
```

obviously does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run three queries. There's no sane way to do this in a single query.

As far as the prepared statement goes, you need to include the `REPLACE()` function in the query, not in the placeholder:

```
$q = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, :string, '')");
$q->execute([ ':string' => $string ]);
```